# HQL Query not executing

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 2 tables Asset and Asset_Dist_Types. Asset is parent and Asset_Dist_Types is a child table. Asset_Dist_Types is having 2 columns asset_id and lkp_dist_type where asset_id is the primary key in Asset table. In Asset_Dist_Types it is a many to many (one asset_id can have multiple lkp_dist_type entries.) In java, we have entity class only for Asset table. In that for Asset_Dist_Type, they have mentioned it as collection of elements. In Asset.java, entry for Asset_Dist_Type is as follows.

```
@CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(name = "ASSET_DIST_TYPE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ASSET_ID"))
    @Column(name="LKP_DIST_TYPE")
    private Set<Integer> distTypes = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(0);
```

Now I would like to update Asset_Dist_Type table's lkp_dist_type column. I have list of asset id's. I have written following query to update it.

```
int hql = entityManager.createQuery(
     "update Asset a set a.distTypes = :distTypeParamId where a.assetId in (:assetIdParam)")
.setParameter("distTypeParamId", distTypeList)
.setParameter("assetIdParam", assetIdListToUpdateLOB)
.executeUpdate();
```

But this is throwing

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute update query.
```

Since I am new to hibernate I am not getting what is the solution. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can some one help..!!!?

Comment: In your Hibernate configuration (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) you can add `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` and then all generated SQL statements are logged to the console. This already might help you, and you can copy that statement into the SQL terminal and execute it there to see which error it produces. If you still have problems, pls. post the statment and the error when executed in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks Johanna for response..! I followed a different way for this and finished it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by following a different way.. I got list of asset id's and list of distribution types. I iterated over the list of asset id's and for each asset id I added list of distribution types and flushed it. It is working now..!

After getting list of asset id's

```
    for(int i=0;i<assetIdListToUpdateLOB.size();i++){

                int assetId = assetIdListToUpdateLOB.get(i);
                System.out.println(assetId);
                List<Asset> assetDetailsList =  entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "select distinct asset from Asset asset "
                                + "left join fetch asset.distTypes dt "
                                + "where asset.assetId = :assetIdParam")
                .setParameter("assetIdParam", assetId).getResultList();
                if(assetDetailsList.size()>0){
                this.asset = assetDetailsList.get(0);
                asset.getDistTypes().clear();
                asset.getDistTypes().addAll(selectedDistributionTypes);
                entityManager.flush();
}
}
```